# Improve performance of Redis to reduce timeout exceptions

Tags: c#, performance, redis

I have a Redis Database on a Centos server, and 3 Windows servers are connected to it with approximately 1,000 reads/writes per second, all of which are on the same local LAN, so the ping time is less than one millisecond.
The problem is at least 5 percent of reading operations are going timeout, while I read maximum 3KB data in a read operation with 'syncTimeout=15', which is much more than network latency.

I installed Redis on bash on my windows 10, and simulate the problem. I also stopped writing operations. However, the problem still exists with 0.5 percent timeouts, while there is no network latency.
I also used a Centos Server in my LAN to simulate the problem, in this case, I need at 100 milliseconds for 'syncTimeout' to be sure the amount of timeout is less than 1 percent.
I considered using some Dictionaries to cache data from Redis, so there is no need to request per item, and I can take advantage of the pipeline. But I came across StackRedis.L1 which is developed as an L1 cache for Redis, and it is not confident in updating the L1 cache.

This is my code to simulate the problem:

```
    var connectionMulti = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(
            "127.0.0.1:6379,127.0.0.1:6380,allowAdmin=true,syncTimeout=15");

    // 100,000 keys
    var testKeys = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\RedisTestKeys.txt");

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var safeI = i;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var serverName = $"server {safeI + 1}";
            var stringDatabase = connectionMulti.GetDatabase(12);
            PerformanceTest($"{serverName} -> String: ",
                key => stringDatabase.StringGet(key), testKeys);
        });
    }
```

and the PerformanceTest method is:

```
private static void PerformanceTest(string testName, Func<string, RedisValue> valueExtractor,
        IList<string> keys)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Starting {testName} ...");
            var timeouts = 0;
            var errors = 0;
            long totalElapsedMilliseconds = 0;

            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                var redisValue = new RedisValue();
                stopwatch.Restart();
                try
                {
                    redisValue = valueExtractor(key);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (e is TimeoutException)
                        timeouts++;
                    else
                        errors++;
                }
                finally
                {
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    totalElapsedMilliseconds += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    lock (FileLocker)
                    {
                        File.AppendAllLines("D:\\TestResult.csv",
                            new[]
                            {
                                $"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()},{redisValue.Length()},{key}"
                            });
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(
                $"{testName} {totalElapsedMilliseconds * 1.0 / keys.Count} (errors: {errors}), (timeouts: {timeouts})");
        });
    }
```

I expect all read operations will be done successfully less than 15 milliseconds.
Achieving this, is Considering L1 cache for a Redis cache a good solution? (It is very fast, in the scale of a nanosecond, but how can I do for syncronizing)
Or Redis can be enhanced by clustering or something else? (While I tested it on bash on my PC, and I did not receive expected result)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or Redis can be enhanced by clustering or something else?

Redis *can* be clustered, in different ways:

- "regular" redis can be replicated to secondary read-only nodes, on the same machine or different machines; you can then send "read" traffic to some of the replicas
- redis "cluster" exists, which allows you to split (shard) the keyspace over multiple primaries, sending appropriate requests to each node
- redis "cluster" can also make use of readonly replicas of the sharded nodes

Whether that is *appropriate or useful* is contextual and needs local knowledge and testing.

> Achieving this, is Considering L1 cache for a Redis cache a good solution?

Yes, it is a good solution. A request you don't make is much faster (and has much less impact on the impact) than a request you *do* make. There are tools for helping with cache invalidation, including using the pub/sub API for invalidations. Redis vNext is also looking into additional knowledge APIs *specifically* for this kind of L1 scenario.